# Writing python code to visualize my dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to plot a visual using python where I have data in two dataset:

```
dataset1 
Id  Values
1     34
1     15
1     19
2     22
2     01
3     55...

dataset2
Id    max   min
1      12    23
2      09    24
3      22    78
```

So here I would like to plot a graph with "IDs" on X axis and "Values" on Y-axis . And also I would like Max and min line on this graph so that I can see how many Ids fall in the range and how many fall out of range..I will be selecting one Id at a time and it should show me the count of Ids along with values and their range on same graph. Can someone show me how can i do this using Python code.

Comment: Have you checked out what Jupyter Notebooks can do for you, particularly the VSC Jupyter Extension?

Comment: no i havent , would look into it

Answer (score 0):

Look into matplotlib. Once you have your datasets in an acceptable format (arrays are the simplest), you can plot as such:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals_1)
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals_2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: what are we having in x_vals and y_vals_1 and 2. I need one graph with both values in it